# Is it necessary for $A$ to be symmetric with non-zero determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, solution-verification

Today, in a Differential Geometry test, I was asked to prove that:

$$S:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^TAx+c=0\}$$

where $A$ is a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix  and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular surface whenever $\det A \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$. Talking to a friend, he gave me his resolution:

(Let's, first, define:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$x \mapsto \langle Ax,x\rangle$$

> If you assume that $A$ is symmetric, the gradient of $f$ in $p$ is $Ap$. Since $c \neq 0$, we have that if $p \in S$, $p$ must not be $0$. Since $\det A \neq 0$, we have that $Ap$ is not $0$, and therefore the derivative is surjective and every point of $S$ is regular.

I gave another solution, where I don't use the fact that $A$ is symmetric and neither the fact that $\det A$ is different than $0$. Therefore, I suspect that there may be something wrong, which I ask of you to verify if that's the case:

*Solution*:

The derivative of the map $x \mapsto \langle Ax,x\rangle$ at a point $p$ is the linear map:

$$f'(x)=\langle A (~~\cdot~~),p\rangle + \langle Ap,~~\cdot~~\rangle$$

Take a point $p \in S$. We know that $\langle Ap,p\rangle=-c$. We show that the derivative is surjective. For that, since it is a linear functional, it is sufficient to show that it is not the zero functional.

But this follows from applying the functional at $p$:

$$f'(x)p=2\langle Ap,p\rangle=-2c \neq 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you do not need to use the two facts $\det A \neq 0$ and $A = A^T$.

First of all, $A^T = A$ is not needed, as for any $A$,

$$x^T A x = x^T\frac 12 (A+A^T) x \ \ \ \ \ \text{(direct checking)}$$

for all $x$. So it is "no harm" to assume that it is symmetric (That is, use $\frac 12 (A+A^T)$ instead of $A$).

So assuming that $A$ is symmetric, then there are eigenvalues $\lambda _i$ with eigenvectors $v_i$ ($v_i$'s can be chosen to be orthonormal), where $i = 1, 2, 3$.

Then under a change of basis, assume that $A$ is diagonal: so

$$x^TA x = \lambda_1 x_1^2 + \lambda_2 x_2^2 +\lambda_3 x_3^2.$$

Now $\det A\neq 0$ if and only if $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. But one easily sees that even if some of them are zero,

$$\{ x^T Ax + c = 0\}$$

for $c\neq 0$ still defines a smooth surface in $\mathbb R^3$.

(In particular, I think your proof is correct, and the assumptions are not needed)